# WCF RIA Service Agent pattern with complex queries

Tags: silverlight, wcf, wcf-ria-services

I'm looking for best practices regarding abstracting my RIA domain context away from my view models to make them data source agnostic. It seems like the best solution I can find is the service agent pattern as described [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2010/12/20/wcf-ria-services-domaincontext-abstraction-strategies-say-that-10-times.aspx). However, what if I have some relatively complex query logic to perform?

For example, currently I have my domain contexts in my view models. Let's say I have a ContactSearchViewModel, where there is a bit of logic involved in constructing the search query:

```
protected EntityQuery<Contact> CreateSearchQuery()
    {
        var query = Context.GetContactsQuery().Where(
                        e => e.First_Name.ToLower().StartsWith(FirstNameSearch.ToLower()) &&
                        e.Last_Name.ToLower().StartsWith(LastNameSearch.ToLower()));
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Phone))
        {
            query = query.Where(q => q.Phone == Phone ||
                                     q.Mobile == Phone ||
                                     q.Work == Phone);
        }
        if (SelectedContactType == "Prospect")
        {
            query = query.Where(q => q.Contact_Type_Id == 1);
        }
        else if (SelectedContactType == "Customer")
        {
            query = query.Where(q => q.Contact_Type_Id == 2);
        }
        return query;
    }
```

Now I could of course have a service agent method with a signature that looks something like `public EntityList<Contact> SearchContacts(string firstName, string lastName, string phone, ContactType contactType)` but imagine if my search queries were even more complex - this interface would become unwieldy. Is there a better alternative, some way I could construct the query in the VM like I do with the domain context? Or should I just suck it up and use some parameter objects?

I would very much prefer to be able to construct the queries on the VM, because I currently have a small hierarchy of VMs which all perform various searches using a base search class and template method for generating queries, kind of like

[image]

Not being able to generate queries from the client would cause a lot of code duplication that I fixed using this inheritance structure.

Comment: I remember a time when I would get a ton of answers within a couple of hours of asking a question like this. Now people only bother to answer simple questions. StackOverflow has really gone downhill.

Comment: I've been thinking through the same question recently. I'm not terribly interested in making the VM data source agnostic (it's really much harder than it appears), but I'd certainly want to decouple things from the DomainContext. I was thinking a good approach might be to add a 'GetContactsQuery' method to the service layer that returned an EntityQuery and then add a 'LoadContacts' method that takes an EntityQuery. A better approach might be to create a query type to 'replay' the query in the service agent. Do either of those approaches seem reasonable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest looking into the Repository pattern. It's part of DDD, but has application in any architecture, IMO. It's purpose is to house query logic.

It seems dirty to give your VM objects query logic, unless that is their [single purpose](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

Comment: Yeah thanks. I ended up using somewhat of a hybrid between repository and service agent. For the VMs I'm talking about their sole purpose is querying - they are view models for search views. All they do is collect search terms (the view state) and use them for queries (view behaviour).